# math notation written in Markdown in Jupyter Notebook not rendered consistently on GitHub

Tags: math, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have the following text with math notation written in Markdown in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
* (linear regression model prediction) : y = $\theta_0$ + $\theta_1$$x_1$ + $\theta_2$$x_2$ + $\theta_n$$x_n$
* (...in vectorized form) ------------ : y = $h_\theta$(x) = $\Theta$.x
```

Somehow when this notebook was uploaded to GitHub, the first part was not rendered correctly, whereas the second part was rendered correctly, as shown in the image below:

[image: problematic rendering of math notation on GitHub]

The same markdown text was rendered correctly when this notebook was open in VSCode:

[image: correctly rendered math notation in notebook opened in VSCode]

May I ask how to solve this inconsistency in rendering math notations via Markdown in Jupyter Notebook?

The problematic jupyter notebook mentioned above is show [here](https://github.com/hopezh/learn_hands_on_ML_v2/blob/master/ch4_training_models.ipynb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the raw file, you can see that it simply contains a markdown cell with that math. So GitHub's Jupyter rendering doesn't recognize this as math ([apparently](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5299#issuecomment-464410372) they use an old `nbconvert` version under the hood).

But probably you can avoid the problem by not using double dollars `$$`. Usually, you would write this in markdown like this:

```
* linear regression model prediction: $y = \theta_0 + \theta_1x_1 + \theta_2x_2 + \theta_nx_n$
* in vectorized form: $y = h_\theta(x) = \Theta.x$
```